# Dispatch action before http call in @ngrx/effects

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx-effects

I want to make http call for that I use effect from rxjs. Now my problem is that I want to dispatch another action like `{ type: LoaderActions.LOADER_START }` before http call. So user can see loading Screen while Http call is requested and once request completed I want to dispatch another action `{ type: LoaderActions.LOADER_END }`.

How can I achieve this using rxjs operators? I am very confused about when to used which operator in rxjs.

**auth.effects.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, of, concat } from 'rxjs';
import { Action, Store } from '@ngrx/store';
import { Actions, Effect, ofType } from '@ngrx/effects';
import * as AuthActions from './auth.actions';
import * as LoaderActions from '../../loader/store/loader.actions';
import {
  map,
  mergeMap,
  switchMap,
  debounce,
  debounceTime,
  tap,
  startWith
} from 'rxjs/operators';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
  })
};
@Injectable()
export class AuthEffects {
  @Effect()
  signInAction$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(AuthActions.TRY_SIGN_IN),
    mergeMap(action =>
      this.http
        .post(
          'http://localhost:8081/auth',
          JSON.stringify({
            username: action['username'],
            password: action['password']
          }),
          httpOptions
        )
        .pipe(
          map(data => {
            if (data['message'] === 'successs') {
              this.router.navigate(['/todo']);
              return { type: AuthActions.SET_AUTH_FLAG, payload: true };
            } else {
              return { type: AuthActions.SET_AUTH_FLAG, payload: false };
            }
          })
        )
    )
  );

  constructor(
    private actions$: Actions,
    private http: HttpClient,
    private router: Router
  ) {}
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `concat` where the first source Observable will be the loading action.

```
@Effect()
signInAction$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$.pipe(
  ofType(AuthActions.TRY_SIGN_IN),
  concatMap(action => concat(
    of({ type: LoaderActions.LOADER_START }),
    this.http...
    of({ type: LoaderActions.LOADER_END }),
  ))
)
```

The `concat` operator will make sure the actions are created in order.

Comment: Answer is fine but I want to call one by one not parallel.How can I do that?

Comment: @baj9032 Use `concatMap` instead of `mergeMap`.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use an extra action for your purpose. Just add a `loading: boolean` property to your state and set it `false` by default. When you dispatch the `TRY_SIGN_IN` you can set it to `true` in the reducer. When the http arrives either with success or with failure you can set the loading state to false again with the dispatch of the `SET_AUTH_FLAG` action.

Then you can select the loading state with a proper selector, but I guess you know what I mean, and use it with Angulars `async` pipe in your templates.

Comment: Ya you are right. But I want to use that action for my whole application.

Comment: Ah, you mean like a global indicator for all outgoing http requests? Have a look at HttpInterceptors then and dispatch the actions from there, but not in each effect.

Comment: I know about that but for learning purpose I want to call from effect.

Answer (score -1):

You should create on more effect listener for `ofType(AuthActions.TRY_SIGN_IN)` and map this action to emit `{ type: LoaderActions.LOADER_START }`. Then, in your effect, that you provided, you should

```
switchMap(data => {
            if (data['message'] === 'successs') {
              this.router.navigate(['/todo']);
              return [{ type: AuthActions.SET_AUTH_FLAG, payload: true }, { type: LoaderActions.LOADER_END }];
            } else {
              return [{ type: AuthActions.SET_AUTH_FLAG, payload: false }, { type: LoaderActions.LOADER_END }];
            }
          })
```

With that approach you'll get desired behavior:
loader action and http request are performing in same time and, when http request will be completed it will emit actions to set auth flag and remove loader

Comment: If I want to dispatch `{ type: LoaderActions.LOADER_END }` at once in my case before if condition then what I can do?

Comment: you can do actual `.dispatch` but I don't recommend to do so. Why do you need to emit it before if? It will work fine if you emit it with set auth flag action (it will be dispatched once in one or another if branch)